# Firebase image is empty after switching views in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage, swiftui

I'm trying to display images from a list of objects stored in `Firebase`. Initially the image loads fine, but if I switch to a different view and return to the list view the image never loads again.

[Gif of the described bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zGi1.gif)

**The image data seems to be saved as expected on both load attempts:**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEEbk.png)

**Below is my code** for the image loader, which uses a url to fetch the images from Firebase Storage, and the list row that contains the image.

**ImageLoader.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dataIsValid = false
    var data:Data?

    func loadImage(url: String) {
        let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
        imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(self.dataIsValid)
                self.dataIsValid = true
                self.data = data
            }
        } 
    }

    func imageFromData() -> UIImage {
        UIImage(data: self.data!)!
    }
}
```

---

**ListRow.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct EventRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader = ImageLoader()
    var imageUrl: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(uiImage: self.imageLoader.dataIsValid ? self.imageLoader.imageFromData() : UIImage())
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 140.0)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0))

        }
        .onAppear {
            self.imageLoader.loadImage(url: self.imageUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to what context these functions are being used. Generally speaking you would want to populate your tableView datasource when the enclosing view opens (in that viewController), and then the tableView would pull it's data from a populated array as it needs to be refreshed or scrolled. Are you trying load each row from within the row itself? If so, that's going to be super laggy and not work correctly due to the asynchronous nature of Firebase. If not, you may want to include a bit more code so we can understand the use case.

Comment: I'm using SwiftUI which uses MVVM instead of MVC model. I created a List() (a SwiftUI view) which loops through my list of objects and populates each ListRow (a view) with data, which is currently just an imageUrl. Yes, the image for each ListRow is loaded within the view itself. Should I be loading the UIImage before I pass it into the subview?

Comment: It looks like `self.imageLoader.imageFromData()` is nil at some point so Image is being initialized with `UIImage()` instead, leading to a blank image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I fixed this was by creating a custom ImageView and handling the image loading within this view. I figured this out by following [this tutorial](https://dev.to/gualtierofr/remote-images-in-swiftui-49jp) and realized that was the step I was missed. If anyone can explain why using the built-in SwiftUI `Image()` causes this issue I would really appreciate it.

**ListRow.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListRow: View {
    var imageUrl: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            FBURLImage(url: imageUrl)
        }
    }
}
```

**FBURLImage.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FBURLImage: View {
    @ObservedObject var imageLoader: ImageLoader

    init(url: String) {
        imageLoader = ImageLoader()
        imageLoader.loadImage(url: url)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage:
            imageLoader.data != nil ? UIImage(data: imageLoader.data!)! : UIImage())
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100.0, height: 140.0)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0))
    }
}
```

**ImageLoader.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: Data?

    func loadImage(url: String) {
        let imageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
        imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error)")
            }
            guard let data = data else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data = data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's a thought for this piece of code `imageLoader.data != nil ? UIImage(data: imageLoader.data!)! : UIImage()` - what happens when imageLoader.data is nil?